# Is there any way to mock useState in react 16 version. Using react testing library for unit testing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, react-testing-library

```
const [isOverflowed, setIsOverflow] = useState(false);

return (

    {isOverflowed
      ? (
        <Tooltip
          title={product}
          classes={{
            tooltip: classes.styleTooltip,
            arrow: classes.arrowStyle,
          }}
          arrow
          placement="top"
        >
)
```

This is the sample code snippet.

Expecting `isOverflowed` to be `true` and `Tooltip` to be render.

Comment: Bit confused, why would you expect `isOverflowed` to be `true`?

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can mock useState, although it is not usually recommended, and can quickly become a mess if you have multiple useStates in your component.
You could try this:

```
jest.spyOn(React, 'useState').mockReturnValueOnce([true, jest.fn()];
```

I don't think you can actually change the state, so you cannot rely on setIsOverflow. you need to set it to true before you render the component.